# IND-CPA Security

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

Given a key $K$ (the key is fixed) and a nonce $N$ (changes from one message to another)

Using a secure Key derivation function (KDF) such as the ANSI-X9.63-KDF with SHA-1 option to derive a key for encryption

Can we reach the IND-CPA security level for our encryption ?

Comment: I assume you mean obtaining an ephemeral key $k_N=$KDF($K | N$)?

Comment: What kind of encryption would you use? If you have a key and a nonce, you shouldn't really need a KDF as well. You could use one in various ways, but ...

Comment: @K.G: Symmetric encryption.

Comment: If you have a key and a nonce, you are done (use AES-GCM or even AES-CBC reach IND-CPA). Why ask about KDFs?

Comment: I am using a secure KDF to randomize the outputs from one message to another. The derived key Kn=KDF(k|n) is then used in OTP namely C = Kn Xor M .

Comment: Why didn't you mention that before? I can't be bothered looking up the details of the KDF, but for any reasonable KDF the answer is yes.

Comment: the community recommend me that instead of KDF I use a PRF(Pseudo Random Function) such as AES (or any block cipher) replacing KDF(K|n) with AES(K,n) where K is the key to AES and n a non-repeating counter or a non-repeating nonce (both implementations give me an IND-CPA encryption ! ?).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Your construction $C=P\oplus KDF(K||N)$ is IND-CPA secure, assuming the KDF is secure, which is reasonable. This construction can be used and is sometimes used with [ECIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) (meaning $E_K(M)=K\oplus M$), but **I'd recommend against using it**. Replacing the KDF with AES is as secure as the above construction, as this mode is called *CTR-mode*, which is proven to be IND-CPA secure.

For practical purposes, as there are better solutions, which already provide higher security levels (IND-CCA2).
I strongly recommend you not to use AES-CTR or "KDF-CTR" but rather use **AES-GCM**, which provides you with full authentication at high speeds with constant-size tags.

Comment: the claim that the construction is IND-CPA can be justified by [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26821/23623).